# GlassFish 6.2.3 does not see javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet

Tags: ubuntu, glassfish, java-ee-8, glassfish-6

I am using glassfish6.2.3 on my local computer. If I add these lines to web.xml

```
 <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

then the following error occurs:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
> at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1577)
> at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1427)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServletClass(StandardWrapper.java:1391)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1257)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1239)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5343)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5588)
> at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:510)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:877)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:860)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:644)
> at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2020)
> at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1666)
> at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:82)
> at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:98)
> at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:267)
> at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:328)
> at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:480)
> at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:199)
> at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:467)
> at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:516)
> at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:512)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:361)
> at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:511)
> at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:542)
> at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:361)
> at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:533)
> at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1441)
> at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1823)
> at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoOperation.run(AutoOperation.java:140)
> at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.deploy(AutoDeployer.java:573)
> at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.deployAll(AutoDeployer.java:460)
> at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.run(AutoDeployer.java:388)
> at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployer.run(AutoDeployer.java:379)
> at org.glassfish.deployment.autodeploy.AutoDeployService$1.run(AutoDeployService.java:209)
> at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:556)
> at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:506)

Otherwise, everything works fine, but the jsf-elements are not displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GlassFish 6.2.3 implements Jakarta EE 9.1 and Faces 3.0. These use the `Jakarta` namespace. Your servlet declaration should therefor be:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

Note that instead of defining a servlet in web.xml, you can also make use of the `@FacesConfig` annotation in your application. This will default map all your views to `.xhtml`.